# brief explanation of method, my java is rusty

Tags: java

Can someone give me brief explanation of this method and any problems. I think it is taking line of input less than 5 words and splitting the line on tabs, newlines, etc. and then doing a comparison to find repeat of word in input line.

```
public static void findNeedles(String haystack, String[] needles){
  if(needles.length > 5){
      System.err.println("Too many words!");
  }

  else{
      int[] countArray = new int[needles.length];
      for(int i = 0; i < needles.length; i++){
          String[] words = haystack.split("[ \"\'\t\n\b\f\r]", 0);
          for(int j = 0; j < words.length; j++){
              if(words[j].compareTo(needles[i]) == 0){
                  countArray[i]++;
        }
    }
      }
      for (int j = 0; j < needles.length; j++) {
          System.out.println(needls[j] + ": " + countArray[j]);
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: @RohitJain, the 0 means something like ["discard empty trailing strings"](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String,%20int%29)

Comment: Maybe if we give him something to accept? I'll give it a go.

Answer (score 3):

Your function takes two arguments, `haystack` a String and `needles` a String array.

It first checks whether the size of `needles` is greater than 5.  If it is, it prints an "error" and subsequently exits.

If not, it then splits the `haystack` string over a number of characters (including single and double quotes, tabs, newlines, word boundaries, form feeds and carriage returns) into an array of words called `words`.

Each "needle" (element of the `needles` array) is compared to each element of the `words` array and if a "needle" is encountered as an element of the `words` array, a "counter" for the respective needle is incremented.

After the search, each needle is displayed along with the number of times it occurred in the haystack.

The function then exits.

Answer (score 1):

It takes two inputs, a String and an array of up to 5 Strings.

It looks through the String comparing each word with each of the words in the array, and counting the matches.

It prints out how many times it found each word in the array in the String.

Answer (score 0):

The method counts the number of "needle" words in a "haystack" text with a maximum of 5 words to look for.

One thing you can improve is to move the split of the text to outside the outer loop.

Another possibility is to get rid of the inner loop alltogether by splitting the haystack using the needles as delimeter giving you `count + 1` pieces of text.